# Putty on linux not showing received data from stm32F407VG

Tags: putty, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, usart, stm32cubeide

I am new in microcontroller and I was trying to send data from stm32F407VG to usb serial port connected to `st-link` using usart2 and `HAL`. I tried to print the data received on  `PuTTy` . On `PuTTy`I set my port which is `/dev/ttyACM0` and selected the baud rate as `9600` which is matching with the baud rate of my stm32F4 board.

But `PuTTy` is not showing anything, Note that I am using Linux Mint.

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Use an oscilloscope to verify that your SBC is actually sending data.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot send data using **HAL_UART** via **ST-Link**. **ST-Link** provides only *Serial Wire Debugging/Trace*. You should select different **UART/USART** port to connect your PC's com port.

Edit: Grammer